# Instagram Rest API call to follow another user

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, instagram-api

I'm trying to call below Instagram Rest API:

[Relationship API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#post_relationship)

to follow another Instagram user, so the final URL looks like:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/5765083049/relationship?action=follow&access_token=5460754.22f7d64.2f500d2741698f182ddb95a26e7

(access token dummy here)

but while testing this on apigee.com, it says this method requires authentication.
I tried adding this via Instagram, but then it says you are not a Sandbox user of this app, even when I am, and the same account is logged in my browser.

The app is live, how do I check these APIs and how do I use these with authentication in Android app?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The action parameter has to be sent separately as a field parameter, not in URL.
This method needs no authentication.